# PivotTableUI in clojurescript from react-pivottable on change interface not render new status

Tags: pivot-table, clojurescript, reagent, shadow-cljs

The component is loaded correctly with the initial data, but the data does not change when the state is changed from the interface, what can I be doing wrong?

[image: not change the table]

```
(ns ui.pivottable.react-pivottable
   (:require ["react-pivottable/PivotTableUI" :default PivotTableUI]
             ["react-pivottable/TableRenderers" :as TableRenderers]
             ["react-plotly.js" :default Plot]
             ["react-pivottable/PlotlyRenderers" :as create-plotly-renderers]
             [reagent.core :as r]))


(defn pivottable []
  (let [state (r/atom  {:data (clj->js [[:name "Alice" :age 30 :city "New York"]
                                         [:name "Bob" :age 35 :city "Chicago"]
                                         [:name "Charlie" :age 40 :city "New York"]])
                         :aggregator-name "Count"
                         :renderer-name "Table"
                         :rows [:name]
                         :cols [:age]})
       component (r/adapt-react-class PivotTableUI)
       plotly-renderers (create-plotly-renderers Plot)
       table-renderers TableRenderers
       params {:rows [:name]
               :cols [:age]
               :on-change #(do (reset! state  (.assign js/Object #js {} %))
                               ;; (reset! state (clj->js %) another try, it's the same)
                            (.log js/console @state))
               :renderers  (.assign js/Object #js {}  plotly-renderers table-renderers)}]

    [component (merge @state params)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Diego. You are using let instead of r/with-let. Therefore, when you change the state of the atom the component is rendered and the atom is initialised with the data again.

Comment: Hi!! Yes, I tried that, the atom return this error: `Uncaught Error: No protocol method ICollection.-conj defined for type object: [object Object]` is the `state` atom when merge